# Does Google Translate's free (non-API) service use neural nets?

Tags: google-translate

Does Google Translate's free (non-API) service, https://translate.google.com/, 
use the [Google Neural Machine Translation (GNMT)](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/languages) technology, or is that restricted to the paid API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does. Google Translate (web service) is based on free API and the "only" difference between free and paid API is a limit of characters per input.

[image: 0]

---

[image: 0]

- **https://cloud.google.com/translate/#features**
- **https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Neural_Machine_Translation**

Comment: It appears [Google Translate first began using NMT in 2016](https://www.blog.google/products/translate/found-translation-more-accurate-fluent-sentences-google-translate/).